# can i memoize custom hook which is graphql query in react?

Tags: reactjs, graph, apollo-client, memoization, usecallback

```
// useMe.tsx //
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { meQuery } from "../__generated__/meQuery";

export const ME_QUERY = gql`
  query meQuery {
    me {
      id
      email
      my_workspaces {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const useMe = () => {
  return useQuery<meQuery>(ME_QUERY, {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-first"
  });
```

};

**This is my custom hook. I am trying to get user info with graphql query and made it to custom hook.**

**But there was some problem, whenever the high-level components state changed,**

**the low-level component which calling custom-hook(useMe) always rerendered**

**so i wanna memoize custom hook with useCallback or useMemo but i can't find right answer**

**please help me, Thank you**

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap the value with `useCallback` is fine

```
const useMeQuery = () => {
  return useQuery<meQuery>(ME_QUERY, {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-first"
  });
export const useMe = useCallbak(useMeQuery)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work outside of a React function component